# Split a file based on date, add trailer with sum and count of the amounts

Tags: bash, text-processing

The source file:

- Header starts with `H`
- Trailer starts with `T`
- Record starts with R
- Delimited by `|~^`

**input file sample**

- Input record starting with R has multiple fields in original source file; here I  just stated 5 fields in the sample.
- Trailer record 3rd column has the count of the records, and 5th column is the sum of the amount columns (3rd column or record lines)
- After splitting, the trailer should be added in the new file with the below format having  count and sum columns.
- INPUT records starting with R will not follow the date order sequence. ex: 1st rec has 2019-03-05 rec and also the last record is also the same date.

**NOTE:**

- INPUT records starting with R will have date fields in multiple columns so please consider the 3rd date field for splitting
- Also, Please **ignore the timestamp in date field**; you can only consider the date and perform split based on date alone. Ideally, all same dated transactions in 3rd column should be moved to new file and add header/trailer with sum and counts.
  ****EDIT******
  My question remains the same, but if the amount field is very large number say (consider amount field data type is Number(31,5) where the decimal points can be upto 5 points, not every time it will be (31,5) if there is any amount with 5 decimals only then value will be upto 5 decimals)

Input file:

```
H|~^20200425|~^abcd|~^sum
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^123562388.23456|~^2018-04-12T12:33:52.27|~^hhh
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^105603.042|~^2018-10-23T12:33:52.27|~^aus
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^2054.026|~^2018-10-24T12:33:52.27|~^usa
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^10.00|~^2018-09-11T12:33:52.27|~^virginia
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^30.00|~^2018-08-05T12:33:52.27|~^ddd
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^15.03|~^2018-10-23T12:33:52.27|~^jjj
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^10.04|~^2018-04-08T12:33:52.27|~^jj
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^20.00|~^2018-07-23T12:33:52.27|~^audg
T|~^20200425|~^8|~^xxx|~^123670130.37256
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

File 1: should be saved as `20190305.txt`

```
H|~^20200425|~^abcd|~^sum
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^105603.042|~^2018-10-23T12:33:52.27|~^aus
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^2054.026|~^2018-10-24T12:33:52.27|~^usa
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^30.00|~^2018-08-05T12:33:52.27|~^ddd
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^20.00|~^2018-07-23T12:33:52.27|~^audg
T|~^20200425|~^4|~^xxx|~^107707.068
```

File 2: should be saved as `20190306.txt`

```
H|~^20200425|~^abcd|~^sum
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^123562388.23456|~^2018-04-12T12:33:52.27|~^hhh
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^10.00|~^2018-09-11T12:33:52.27|~^virginia
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^15.03|~^2018-10-23T12:33:52.27|~^jjj
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^10.04|~^2018-04-08T12:33:52.27|~^jj
T|~^20200425|~^4|~^xxx|~^123562423.30456
```

Comment: Why do you think that a `for` loop should have a better performance than `awk`? If you have bad experience, show the `awk` script. Running a specialized tool is often faster than a shell script.

Comment: Do you have real floating point numbers or only integers printed in floating point format, i.e. with trailing `.00`? Please [edit] your question to add requested information, don't answer in comments.

Comment: Awk is orders of magnitude faster than the shell. In fact, it is usually the fastest solution you can find. But it is 100% certain to be much, much faster than a shell for loop. And R loops are very, slow, so it will also be _much_ slower than an R loop.

Comment: No,my only concern is if there is somr IO issur or some cluster issue in middle we may loose track of what it has splitted. Thats my major concen. sorry if im wrong im new to shell scripting. Suggest some better ways to achieve this.

Comment: I have real floating value it's not integer.

Comment: Achieve what? Please [edit] your question and explain what you need. I am afraid I can't understand at all. Do you just need to split the file, or do you also need some calculation? Are you just trying to make new files with the data of each day?

Comment: How large are your files? Can they fit in memory? Or are they many GB?

Comment: Hi Terdon, Im sorry for not being clear.I have a input file which has header, records and trailer. Records are having multiple dates. So i need to split the file based on date column to individual files. Post splitting i need add header(can use same header in input file) and trailer with count of the records and sum of the amount column of all records. Hope this isclear. File size is around 500 to 600 mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an `awk` solution:

```
awk -F'\\|~\\^' '{ 
            if($1=="H"){ 
                head=$0
            }
            else if($1=="T"){
                foot=$1"|~^"$2
                foot4=$4
            }
            else{
                date=$3;
                sub("T.*","", date);
                data[date][NR]=$0;
                sum[date]+=$4; 
                num[date]++
            }
           }
           END{
            for(date in data){
                file=date".txt";
                gsub("-","",file); 
                print head > file; 
                for(line in data[date]){
                    print data[date][line] > file
                } 
                printf "%s|~^%.3f|~^%s|~^%.3f\n", foot, num[date], 
                                              foot4, sum[date] > file
            }
           }' file
```

When run on your example data, this produces:

```
$ cat 20190305.txt
H|~^20200425|~^abcd|~^sum
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^105603.042|~^2018-10-23T12:33:52.27|~^aus
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^2054.026|~^2018-10-24T12:33:52.27|~^usa
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^30.00|~^2018-08-05T12:33:52.27|~^ddd
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-05T12:33:52.27|~^20.00|~^2018-07-23T12:33:52.27|~^audg
T|~^20200425|~^4.000|~^xxx|~^107707.068

$ cat 20190306.txt
H|~^20200425|~^abcd|~^sum
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^123562388.23456|~^2018-04-12T12:33:52.27|~^hhh
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^10.00|~^2018-09-11T12:33:52.27|~^virginia
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^15.03|~^2018-10-23T12:33:52.27|~^jjj
R|~^abc|~^2019-03-06T12:33:52.27|~^10.04|~^2018-04-08T12:33:52.27|~^jj
T|~^20200425|~^4.000|~^xxx|~^123562423.305
```

Also, since you seem to think that awk is slow, I tested this on a large file. To create my test file, I ran this:

```
perl -e '@d=<>; print $d[0]; $str=join("",@d[1..$#d-1]); print $str x 3500000; print $d[$#d]' file > bigFile
```

This creates a 1.9G file with 28000002 lines, where the 1st line is the header of your original file, the last line is the footer of your original and the lines between are 3.5 million repetitions of your original file contents. I then ran my awk on this file (note that I have enough RAM for this, you will need at least 618M of free RAM):

```
$ time awk -F'\\|~\\^' '{ if($1=="H"){head=$0} else if($1=="T"){foot=$1"|~^"$2; foot4=$4;} else{date=$3; sub("T.*","", date);data[date][NR]=$0;sum[date]+=$4;num[date]++;} }END{for(date in data){file=date;gsub("-","",file); sub("T.*",".txt",file); print head > file; for(line in data[date]){print data[date][line] > file} printf "%s|~^%s|~^%s|~^%s\n", foot, num[date], foot4, sum[date] > file } }' bigFile 

real    2m8.603s
user    2m0.610s
sys     0m6.795s
```

So, 2 minutes to process 1.9G of data on 28,000,002 lines. That is pretty fast (although [Isaac's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/583256/22222) was faster at 1m 30, and uses less memory, so UI suggest you use that instead). I can absolutely guarantee that you will never get it this fast with a shell `for` loop. Nor, for that matter, with an R for loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. It is working fine! Appreciate you for spending some time and giving me the solution. In your code you have used data[date][NR]=$0; sum[date]+=$4; num[date]++ these, may i know are these array concepts or these are kind of map which holds key and value pairs? Can you please explain to me this part if you don't mind.

Comment: @hunter all arrays in awk are associative (which means they are what you call a map with key/value combinations). So yes, these are associative arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot! can you please explain what does this data[date][NR]=$0 step exactly do? It reads the entire line if the it starts with 'R' and stores the line for that particular date in an associative array?

Comment: @hunter yes. This is all standard awk stuff. If you don't understand it, you should probably read some  basic awk tutorial.

Comment: Hey@terdon, When I'm testing the above code it's behaving cranky exactly in the sum of the amount based on the date part i.e. exactly when the amount is very large say 386657893342.898836(considering amount column can be number(31,5) datatype) it's unable to sum and provide me with the exact decimal precession. I tried  using bc(bash caluclator) as it gives exact sum value but unable to incorporate the change with the above code. Pls, suggest me on this. Kind of stuck at this point

Comment: Also, For the footer code I have used printf "%s|~^%s|~^%s|~^%.15g\n", foot, num[date], foot4, sum[date] > file used "%.15g" instead of "%s" this resolves to some part. If the total sum value is 15 digits (including decimal points) this is working. If the sum value exceeds 15 digits This "%.15g" isn't working expected. Should I use OFMT or CONVFMT any such to display all the digits in the sum?

Comment: @hunter it should be enough to just use `%f` instead of `%s`. See updated answer. However, if you need anything more, please post a new question. This time, make sure your examples accurately represent your real data so we don't need to do this back and forth in the comments.

Comment: Thanks I will surely do that. using %f precision, it will be always 6 digits by default. In your 1st output trailer has 6 decimal points but expected one is 107707.068(3 decimals). I tried %f but couldn't achieve the desired output. Even in 2nd output, there has been a 0 added at the end of the sum making 6 decimals again

Comment: @hunter then just use `%.3f`. See updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, It's not always 3 decimals. When I sum I should print exact value be it 3 decimals 0r 5 decimals(It's based on the amount for that particular date.If it has 5 decimals for particular date sum should be 5.if it has only 2 decimal amount should display only 2). I think I edited the question, in the same way, sorry for not being clear

Comment: @hunter I have no idea what you need any more. Just ask a new question. Please.

Answer (score 2):

With your last edit you have changed the whole question.

Now, for each line, the timestamp has to be converted into the file name.
That is, from `2019-03-06T12:33:52.27` to `20190306`.
That alone require quite some string processing, which is never fast on any language.

That small part could be done in awk with:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\\|~\\^";OFS="|~^"}
     $1=="R"{
              t=gensub(/-/, "","g",$3)
              s=gensub(/T.*/,"",1,t);
              $3=s
            }
     1
' "file" >"file.adj"
```

Then, there is still the (your initial question) of dividing the file based on the date of the date of the timestamp. The list of minimum changes required are:

- for each line on the input copy it to an specific (given by $3) file.
- while that is done, also count lines (for each file)
- and sum the values on field `4`.
- When all the input lines have been processed, print the tail to each file.

The whole process could be done in awk as this:

```
awk 'BEGIN  { FS="\\|~\\^"; OFS="|~^" }
     $1=="H"{ header=$0; hdr=$2 }
     $1=="R"{
              t=gensub(/-/, "","g",$3)
              file=gensub(/T.*/,"",1,t);
              sum[file]+=$4
              if(count[file]==0){ print header >file }
              count[file]++
              print $0 >>file
            }
     END    {
              for( i in sum ){
                  print "T",hdr,count[i],"xxx",sum[i] >> i;
                  close(i)
                  }
            }
' "file"
```

Using the Perl repetition for 1 Million times of the source file it takes the whole file to be processed only 49.32 seconds. Minimum use of memory (only sum and count per day needs to stay in memory). That seems pretty fast to me.